# Multi-Domain Login

Tags: node.js, authentication, multiple-domains, docpad

I'm working on a little node.js-project, and while googling alot, I kinda got a bit confused, but maybe some of you are able to point me towards the road again.

Several websites are generated by [DocPad](https://github.com/bevry/docpad) (excellent piece of software), and hosted on different domains.

All these websites shall now get a "login module" (which is also written in Node.js, using passport). Visually, it will look similar to the excellent login-slider from Web-Kreation ([Here](http://web-kreation.com/demos/Sliding_login_panel_jquery/) a demo). My plan was to use nginx and route all the /login-requests to the login-app, which is working fine.

The problem is rather related to the multiple domains, and the clientside implementation of it all. All logins use the same database.

Can I somehow use both together, and create the session-cookies from the Login-Module (which could use the same domain all the time)?

Comment: Think I need to clarify my question:
Can I simply set the cookie for the login-app (always from login.example.com) while the site uses a different domain (f.e. superexample.com).

How would I integrate the common login-part? My guess is pulling it with an XMLHTTPRequest, but i'm utterly confused by now.

Answer (score 2):

I'm answering my own question for reference, in case someone else comes across the same problem.

In the end, I solved my problem by having a bit of a different setup. Instead of a module, using the dns of each page, I use a central login-application for all sites. The sites itself do not require to access any personal information, so that's not a problem.

DocPad is still being used to generate the different websites (works excellent - I know I say this very often, but if there's a brilliant piece of software out, there's no reason to not mention it once in a while) statically, and all static content is delivered to the user using a CDN.

The login-system is a node.js-application using Redis as the only database. It is integrated via a simple iframe on all pages rendered by DocPad on login.example.com.

Answer (score 1):

After successful login in 'login-app' you can create encrypted string with info about current user. You can pass this string back in get/post parameter with redirect to necessary domain. Encription key is known only to the 'login-app' and your websites. You can trust this encrypted data. It is necessary to make sure that every time the key is different for the same user. For example you can add the information about the time of login or random. After decrypting the data you can set authorization cookie for a particular domain.

Comment: You're elegantly describing what is happening on the serverside of the app, which is not really the problem. I tried to clarify my question in an additional comment.